# Trying to figure out what/where an exit code is coming from in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm running a script that uses an API from a software provider to download data on 1 min intervals. For some reason, it always seems to run for a while before eventually stopping with exit code

> Process finished with exit code -559038737

I thought this was probably something to do with their API so I contacted my provider and they are saying it's definitely not something coming from their end.

I'm using PyCharm so I wasn't sure if this was something I'd have to contact them about to figure out what it meant? I tried searching here but doesn't seem like it's a very common exit code so don't really know how to troubleshoot it.

If anyone knows what causes this exit code or the process by which I can try to figure that out for myself, it'd be very helpful.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Usually I get that when I'm making an error in the API request... Can you tell us what API you're using and what is the request ?

Comment: -559038737 in hex is the oft-used joke exit code `0xDEADBEEF`. grep your source code for that...

Comment: sorry - I'm fairly new to python. what does 'grep' my code mean? Also, Alex_6, are you looking for a specific line of code? http://partners.cqg.com/api-resources/cqg-data-and-trading-apis. This is the link to the API. I'm using an augmented version of the TimedBarsDaily sample file located in the Python samples folder